# Getting values from Child Windows

Tags: jquery, parent

Here is what I am trying to do. I am using IE.Object to navigate to a page. I then add a new column to a table along with check boxes and a button to this new window. I am trying to figure out how to return the value of those checked box's back to the parent window.

Will I need to append js to the child window to create a function to do that? Not sure the best way to approach it.

So far I have my code navigating to the window, adding the button and checkboxes. Now I am just trying to figure out how to go about returning those values of the checked box's back to my parent window / script.

Comment: We could use some code... How about a JSFiddle example?

Comment: I dont think it will help much; its all internal sites.

http://jsfiddle.net/gWDpd/

On the window is opening, there is an HTML table now with checkboxes on each row and a button on the top. I need to pass the value of the checkbox back to the parent window.

Comment: However i must add; i cant edit the child windows content myself to include the needed functions; can only add to it through jquery as its not a site I have access to.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with something like this.

**In the child:**

```
window.onunload = function () {
    var checked = [],
        inputs  = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
        i       = 0,
        max     = inputs.length;

    for (;i < max; i += 1) {
        if (inputs[i].checked) {
            checked.push(inputs[i]);
        }
    }

    // Assume you have some variable in the parent name childChecked that you are monitoring
    window.opener.childChecked = checked; 
};
```